# Accessing driver IOControl from user application without administrator priviledge

Tags: windows, io, driver

I have written a windows kernel-mode driver to access memory space of a PCI Express board and I am able to communicate with driver's IO Control using CreateFile and DeviceIOControl functions. Everything looks good except the fact that user application needs to run with administrator privileges since read/write access to PCI device is needed. This is a challenge in my application because I cannot expect my users to have administrator rights when running application. To address this problem, I have come up with following ideas so far:

1) Creating a named pipe in driver and accessing it in user application but I'm not sure if driver has access to windows APIs for creating and accessing a named pipe.

2) Creating a windows service which runs with administrator privileges and becomes an interface between user application and driver. Although it's practical, this solution seems to be overkill.

I appreciate any comment on above solutions and also the common practice for communicating with a driver.

Thanks

Comment: Using DeviceIOControl() can certainly be a killer poke so admin access rights are normally required.  The driver installer determines the value for the Security key.  Look at c:\windows\inf\wvid.inf for an example, [Vid_Device.NT.AddReg] section.  Doing it programmatically after install is [discussed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563755(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Your driver can assign whatever permissions are appropriate on the device objects it creates.  The default settings only allow administrators to send I/O control requests to a device, but you can configure it however you like.

The MSDN section titled [Securing Device Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563688(v=vs.85).aspx) covers this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for providing your comments. `WdfDeviceInitAssignSddlString` is what I needed to use in my KMDF. This API specifies priviledges required to access I/O controller of driver.